# Implementation of elliptic gamma function

Tags: special-functions

I need to perform series expansion in `p, q` (to order `order`) of products/ratios of the so-called elliptic gamma functions, commonly defined by the infinite product,
$$
\Gamma(z,p,q) = \prod_{m,n \ge 0} \frac{1 - z^{-1}p^{m+1}q^{n+1}}{1 - z p^m q^n} \ .
$$

However, in practice I find this definition (with the dummy variables $m, n$ truncated to `order`) is very **slow** to work with.

I wonder if there are better ways to implement this function? Note that the function will be used abstractly, instead of numerically.

Answer (score 8):

You can do one of the products exactly, and the other numerically, to gain a factor of >20 in speed:

```
(* original: double-infinite product *)
Γ1[z_?NumericQ, p_?NumericQ, q_?NumericQ] :=
  NProduct[(1 - z^-1 p^(m + 1) q^(n + 1))/(1 - z p^m q^n),
           {m, 0, ∞}, {n, 0, ∞}]

(* simpler: single-infinite product *)
Γ2[z_?NumericQ, p_?NumericQ, q_?NumericQ] :=
  NProduct[QPochhammer[(p q^(1 + n))/z, p]/QPochhammer[q^n z, p],
           {n, 0, ∞}]

(* same but symmetrized over p&q to maintain the symmetry *)
Γ3[z_?NumericQ, p_?NumericQ, q_?NumericQ] :=
  Sqrt@NProduct[(QPochhammer[p*q/z p^k, q]*QPochhammer[p*q/z q^k, p])/
                (QPochhammer[z p^k, q]*QPochhammer[z q^k, p]),
  {k, 0, ∞}]

Γ1[0.3, 0.17, 0.09] // RepeatedTiming
(*    {0.0538385, 1.47214}    *)

Γ2[0.3, 0.17, 0.09] // RepeatedTiming
(*    {0.00227641, 1.47214}    *)

Γ3[0.3, 0.17, 0.09] // RepeatedTiming
(*    {0.00333879, 1.47214}    *)
```

The formulas used are

```
Product[(1 - z^-1 p^(m + 1) q^(n + 1))/(1 - z p^m q^n), {m, 0, ∞}]
(*    QPochhammer[(p q^(1 + n))/z, p]/QPochhammer[q^n z, p]    *)

Product[(1 - z^-1 p^(m + 1) q^(n + 1))/(1 - z p^m q^n), {n, 0, ∞}]
(*    QPochhammer[(p^(1 + m) q)/z, q]/QPochhammer[p^m z, q]    *)
```

Of course, a [`QPochhammer`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/QPochhammer.html) symbol is nothing more than the infinite product given; but we can assume that the internal evaluation of `QPochhammer` is much more efficient than `NProduct`.

Comment: (+1) it's astonishing that `QPochhammer` is performing so much better than `NProduct`. Somehow related(?): perhaps this approach generalizes nicely for situations involving ${}_2F_1$? Namely, write them as `Pochhammer` symbols using the standard formuale?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! The function will be used abstractly (`z, p, q` all symbols not numerics) in my project, and will be series expanded in `p, q`. I tested some simple expressions and expansions, and, unfortunately, your suggestion seems roughly the same as the simple product approach. It would be nice if you could also suggest on abstract use.

Comment: (I now added emphasis on abstract use in the question)

Comment: I'd recommend you head to the [math stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com) and ask for help with finding concise expressions for calculating these derivatives. Once you know a concise formulation, it will be easier to write fast Mathematica code for calculating them. For example, can your $\Gamma$ and its derivatives be expressed as [Mellin–Barnes integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barnes_integral)? Or as [hypergeometric functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function)? This would simplify and speed up and follow-up work.